# Using moment's isoWeekday to create a date grid

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, momentjs

I am trying to create a date grid for a calendar. I have it working when Sunday is designated as the "first day of the week."

## Using Sunday as the starting day of the week (working)

Given the month of March, 2017, the grid would start with `Sunday, February 26, 2017`, and end with `Saturday, April 1, 2017`. This is how I am doing it:

```js
let now = moment('2017/03/06/', 'YYYY/MM/DD');
let startOfGrid = now.clone().startOf('month').startOf('week');
let endOfGrid = now.clone().endOf('month').endOf('week');

console.log(startOfGrid.format()); // Sunday, Febrary 26, 2017
console.log(endOfGrid.format()); // Saturday, April 1, 2017
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I then pass those two dates off to fill in the dates in between which gives me all the dates for a calendar grid.

---

## Using Saturday or Monday as the starting day of the week (not working)

I need to be able to support the week starting on either Saturday, or Monday, but I can't seem to get the settings right, and the results aren't consistent across months. Let's use Saturday as an example:

Given the month of March again, but setting the start of the week to `saturday`, and using the `startOf('isoWeek')`, I end up with Monday as the start of the week (should be Saturday):

```js
let now = moment('2017/03/06/', 'YYYY/MM/DD');
let startOfGrid = now.clone().startOf('month').isoWeekday('saturday').startOf('isoWeek');
let endOfGrid = now.clone().endOf('month').isoWeekday('saturday').endOf('isoWeek');

console.log(startOfGrid.format()); // Monday, Febrary 27, 2017
console.log(endOfGrid.format()); // Sunday, April 2, 2017
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I should be getting a Saturday as the beginning of the grid, and a Friday as the ending.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to some pieces put together from https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/ and https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/, you can use `moment.updateLocale` to override the locale configuration globally, like so:

```js
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    week: {
        dow: 6  //week starts on saturday
    }
});
```

This will affect all moment objects created in the future, but not those already created. Alternatively, you can define your own locale if you want some more flexibility:

```js
moment.defineLocale('en-mod', {
    parentLocale: 'en',
    week: {
        dow: 6  //week starts on saturday
    }
});
```

Note that this will also set the locale globally, so you may want to immediately invoke `moment.locale('en');` to change back to default (or whatever locale you had set initially).

Then, with your custom locale definition, you can use it on individual moment objects, i.e.: `moment().locale('en-mod');`